# How to make a list of the categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How use 'post_category' to show me the list of all categories?

I want to show here:

```
<select name="category">
</select>
```

Thx for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a function for this. Use wp_dropdown_categories.

A full list of parameters can be found here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Basic example:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'name' => 'category' ) ); ?>
```

I've set the name to category to match the version you gave in the question.